# Why does wolfram alpha not give an integral of $e^{-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus

I am considering the integral

$$I=\int e^{-x^2}.$$

Wolfram Alpha gives an answer to this integral with some strange erf thing. Surely it is quite clear that there is an answer to this, and it is $$I=-\frac{1}{2x}e^{-x^2}.$$ This can be seen because $$\frac{d}{dx}\Big(-\frac{1}{2x}e^{-x^2}\Big)=-\frac{1}{2x}(-2x)e^{-x^2}=e^{-x^2}$$ and by considering the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Use the product rule in your final equation

Comment: Your derivation of $I$ is not correct.

Comment: Closed because it was a far too simple question and I was being silly.

Comment: The question is still valid, just because your method had a calculus error doesn't mean that a sufficient answer cannot be given for why wolfram does not give an answer. You should edit your question and see if someone will post a good answer.

Comment: @ ODP : Why do you think that << Wolfram Alpha gives an answer to this integral with some strange erf thing. >>. The function erf(x) isn't a strange thing, it is a well-known function, that one can use on the same manner as cos(x), exp(x), ln(x), sqrt(x), Gamma(x) and many other. The only difference between them is that you know some of them and you don't know yet the others. A paper for general public on this subject : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the product rule in your derivation:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\Big(-\frac{1}{2x}e^{-x^2}\Big)=-\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{x^2}e^{-x^2}-\frac{1}{x}2x e^{-x^2})=\frac{1}{2x^2}e^{-x^2}+e^{-x^2}$$

Comment: Is it not true that $$\frac{d}{dx}e^{f(x)}=f'(x)e^{f(x)}?$$

Comment: Oh the product rule of course

Comment: that *is* true, but that is *not* what you wrote.

Comment: please see here for more info on this actually very interesting subject: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath045/kmath045.htm

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that "erf thing" aka the error function is the integeral.. well

erf(x) = $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$

It has a long history statistics and is the basis of the normal distribution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

As for your differentiation.

$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{-1}{2x} e^{-x^2} = \frac{1}{2x^2}e^{-x^2} + e^{-x^2} $